# Database created from assetu

Tags: android, database, sqlite

My DBHelper class is a database of asset. And I have a problem writing it No such file or directory
The asset I have printer-specific file with the name dbm.db (this is the database)
This is the class:

```
package com.example.dbt7;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "dbm.db";
    private Context context;
    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
        File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
           try {
                copyDatabase(dbFile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    private void copyDatabase(File dbFile) throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (is.read(buffer) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer);
        }

        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
    } 
}
```

ok it does not report any error ...

Now a problem when I want to open in this activity
And now when I turn it so it falls

```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



      AssetDatabaseOpenHelper otevreno = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(this);
      otevreno.openDatabase();
   }
```

This problem it throws

```
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dbt7/com.example.dbt7.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error creating source database
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.example.dbt7.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:29)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.example.dbt7.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    ... 11 more
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.example.dbt7/databases/dbm.db (No such file or directory)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:97)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:69)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.example.dbt7.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.copyDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:38)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    at com.example.dbt7.AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.openDatabase(AssetDatabaseOpenHelper.java:27)
07-01 01:25:15.517: E/AndroidRuntime(32039):    ... 14 more
```

Where is the problem?
I don't have bad DB_NAME? What would be there when I have a db jmenom dbm. db in assets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AssetDatabaseOpenHelper` is not constructed properly! If you are going to use this class to manage all process with your database in your app, you should build it another way. Here is an example how you can initialise your database from asset folder and use it in your whole app :

```
public class AssetDatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // DATABASE
    private static SQLiteDatabase mSqliteDb;
    private static AssetDatabaseOpenHelper mInstance;
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "your.db";
    private static Context mContext;

    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, version);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void initialise() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            if (!checkDatabase()) {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            mInstance = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(mContext, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            mSqliteDb = mInstance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
    }

    public AssetDatabaseOpenHelper getInstance(){
        return mInstance;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
        return mSqliteDb;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    private static void copyDataBase() {

        try {
            // Open your local db as the input stream
            InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

            // Path to the just created empty db
            String outFileName = getDatabasePath(mContext);

            // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
            File f = new File(mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdir();

            // Open the empty db as the output stream
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

            // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkDatabase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            try {
                String myPath = getDatabasePath();
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                        SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
                checkDB.close();
            } catch (Exception e) { }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
        }
        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    private static String getDatabasePath() {
        return mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
                + DATABASE_NAME;
    }

}
```

and in your MainActivity you should initialise your db like :

```
AssetDatabaseOpenHelper mDbHelper = new AssetDatabaseOpenHelper(this, null, 1);
mDbHelper.initialise();
```

Comment: The method getDatabasePath() in the type AssetDatabaseOpenHelper is not applicable for the arguments (Context)

Comment: just remove mContext on that line, it's a type mistake.

Comment: this code runs perfect but raises an exception android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database, but still +1 for this code for these lines String outFileName = getDatabasePath(mContext); & File f = new File(mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX); which i used in my own code. Thank you Android-Developer